# Preload next remote file while playing another using just_audio

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I'm building a music quiz app with Flutter and just_audio. App plays one remote mp3 at a time. Then user proceeds to another screen and gets the new file.
Currently, it takes some time to load file for a new screen. I'm trying to optimize and preload the next remote mp3 while playing the current one.
Load method of `AudioPlayer` works only with current file. Same for `LockCachingAudioSource` class.

Is there a way to do this with `just_audio`? Maybe I should switch between two `AudioPlayer` objects or there is a better way to implement such preload?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only other mechanism to preload is `ConcatenatingAudioSource` but in that case the playback auto-advances to the next item, so it's not applicable to your problem.

Therefore, the correct solution is as you suspected. Have one player for the question, and a second player for the answer. Each player will maintain its own audio buffer, allowing you to preload the answer audio into the second buffer (via `load()` or `setAudioSource(preload: true)`) without affecting the first player's buffer.